KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "View Layer" not found' when launching blender with external script
When I execute the following code within Blender, it works well regardless of whether it's version 3.x or 4.x. However, if I try to use it by launching Blender with a specific argument to open a Blender file containing this script (e.g., blender --python myscript.py myfile.blend), the file opens correctly but the script triggers an error after Blender's addons load:
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "View Layer" not found'

I tried to override the context to force it to the Outliner, but encountered errors with that approach as well. Any thoughts?
import bpy
          
class ChrisMemoriserInvisible(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.memorise_invisible"
    bl_label = "Minimal Operator"
    
    @classmethod
    def description(cls, context, properties):
        return "get meshes and collection visibility"
        
    def execute(self, context):
        print("\n\r---- S T A R T I N G ---------------------\n\r")
        # Recursivly transverse collection
        def collections_recursively(collection):
            print(">>collection child: " + collection.name + " - invisible : " + str( collection.hide_viewport))
            if collection.hide_viewport == True:
                print("collection invisible :" + collection.name)
                f.write("collection>>" + collection.name +  "\r")
            for child in collection.children:
                collections_recursively(child)
       
        # Recursivly transverse layer_collection
        def recurLayerCollection(layerColl):
            found = None
            for layer in layerColl.children:
        #        print(">>>",layer.name)
                if layer.exclude == True:
                    print(layer.name,"true")
                    print("collection unchecked :" + layer.name)
                    f.write("layer>>" + layer.name +  "\r")
                elif layer.exclude == False:
                    print(layer.name,"false")
                    
                found = recurLayerCollection(layer)
                if found:
                    return found
         
        view_layer = bpy.context.scene.view_layers["View Layer"]
        obj_visibles = []
                
        with open("D:/_Chris/- SCRIPTS -/import_collection_invisible_mesh.ini","w") as f:              
            
            for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
                if o.hide_get() == 0:
                    print ("visible : " + o.name)
                else:
                    print ("invisible : " + o.name )
                    f.write("mesh>>" + o.name +  "\r")  
               
                if o.hide_viewport == True:
                    print ("invisible : " + o.name )
                    f.write("meshview>>" + o.name +  "\r")  
                    
                    
            # collection with eye closed or not
            for collection in bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children:
                print ("----------------------------------------")
                print(collection.name, ' - ', collection.hide_viewport)  
                collections_recursively(collection)  
                
            # collection unchecked or not
            for layer_collection in view_layer.layer_collection.children:
                if layer_collection.exclude == True:
                    print(layer_collection.name,"true")
                    print("collection unchecked :" + layer_collection.name)
                    f.write("layer>>" + layer_collection.name +  "\r")
                elif layer_collection.exclude == False:
                    print(layer_collection.name,"false")
                    
                layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection)
            
        f.closed    
        return {'FINISHED'} 

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ChrisMemoriserInvisible)
   
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ChrisMemoriserInvisible)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    bpy.ops.wm.memorise_invisible()


UPDATE: the error I get from the console, the script I call is named cs_append_get_hidden_collections.py



@Chris : good question and yes if I go in the outliner in Display Mode > Scenes > View Layers > View Layer is present. So I have created an other new test file with 3.6.9 version and by default the view layer is named ViewLayer without space in it. If I fire my script again changing "View Layer" to "ViewLayer" I don't get any error but the list of objects is as if it was a virgin file without anything inside : it only list a camera and a light with a collection. It looks like blender is not seeing the loaded scene but a brand new one

Notice that the error appears before it reads the blend file. That is because your command should specify the blend file first and then the python script argument like this:
blender myfile.blend --python myscript.py

The issue arose because the command was structured with the --python script argument first, followed by the .blend file specification. In Blender's background mode, this sequence initially executes the Python script with a default setup where the view layer is named "ViewLayer" without a space. Consequently, the error occurs before Blender reads the .blend file specified. To resolve this, ensure that your command specifies the blend file first and then the Python script argument, like this:
blender myfile.blend --python myscript.py


